# Comparing forecast models for signs of conversion

Tags: panel-data, dataset, convergence

I am trying to analyze two external forecast models for weather data that each generate hourly forecasts twice a day for one week ahead. Thereby I get a panel-like dataset, in which I am interested in knowing if at some point the forecast from one provider will tend to converge towards that of the other. Each forecast also comes with different sensitivity series, meaning I essentially have a bit more than two series to work with. 
I don't seem to be able to find others who have worked with similar issues. In general, I am not interested in knowing whether the providers are correct in their forecasts, since I mainly care about predicting the tendencies of convergence. 
Do you guys know of any statistical tools which could be of use for this problem?

Comment: You might be able to check the panel series of absolute differences for a downward trend. By "at some point", do you mean that the 7 day-ahead forecasts are systematically closer together than the 3 day-ahead ones, or that as time passes, the 3 day-ahead forecasts tend to get closer together? Two different questions.

Comment: @StephanKolassa with 'at some point' I mean that the if we see each multistep ahead forecast as a generation and we are observing the forecasted values for one point in time across both providers and forecast generations, then the two providers might indicate quite different estimates for that point forecast, which of course updates for each 'generation', however, we might also see that as we approach the point in time that we care about, a new generation from one of the providers might have the forecast converge towards the forecasted value of the other provider implying that they agree more.